# Fetching data from collection 'profiles' in Cloud Firestore with SwiftUI. Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'UserProfile'

Tags: firebase, types, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, document

I'm new to developing, looking for some help.

I've managed to create a collection of profiles stored in Cloud Firestore. I now want to retrieve the signed in users profile information to use throughout my app.

Here is what I have so far:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var user: UserProfile = UserProfile(uid: "", firstName: "", email: "", gender: "")
    
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func fetchProfileFirstName () {
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "" 
    db.collection("profiles").document(userId)
      .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
      guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
      }
      guard let data = document.data() else {
        print("Document data was empty.")
        return
      }
      print("Current data: \(data)")
      self.user = data
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error: `'Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'UserProfile'`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user uses a UserProfile structure, but when you are assigning that document data to that user variable, the document data is not in the form of an  UserProfile, it is in the form of a [String: Any].

All you have to do is convert that [String: Any] to UserProfile:

Replace

```
self.user = data
```

with

```
self.user = UserProfile(uid: document.get("uid") as? String ?? "", firstName: document.get("first name") as? String ?? "", email: document.get("email") as? String ?? "", gender: document.get("gender") as? String ?? "")
```

Comment: Please don't map data manually. Save yourself time and headaches by using Firestore's Codable support. See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase supports the Codable API, which enables you to perform type-safe mapping from Firebase documents to Swift structs.

Here's what you need to do to implement it:

1. Add `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` to your `Podfile`
2. Import `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`
3. Make sure your `UserProfile` struct implements `Codable`
4. When reading documents, you can call `return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserProfile.self)`
5. When writing documents, call `try db.collection("profiles").addDocument(from: userProfile)`

I covered this in detail in [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/), and also recorded [this video](https://youtu.be/3-yQeAf3bLE).